# Valores repetidos al hacer INNER JOIN doble

Tags: mysql

Al realizar una consulta imprime valores repetidos al hacer `INNER JOIN` doble.

Mi código:

```
SELECT
     tec_sale_items.`sale_id` AS tec_sale_items_sale_id,
     tec_sale_items.`quantity` AS tec_sale_items_quantity,
     tec_sale_items.`unit_price` AS tec_sale_items_unit_price,
     tec_sale_items.`subtotal` AS tec_sale_items_subtotal,
     tec_sale_items.`product_name` AS tec_sale_items_product_name,
     tec_customers.`name` AS tec_customers_name,
     tec_customers.`phone` AS tec_customers_phone,
     tec_customers.`email` AS tec_customers_email,
     tec_customers.`cf1` AS tec_customers_cf1,
     tec_sales.`customer_name` AS tec_sales_customer_name,
     tec_sales.`date` AS tec_sales_date,
     tec_sales.`id` AS tec_sales_id,
     tec_sale_items.`product_code` AS tec_sale_items_product_code,
     tec_products.`code` AS tec_products_code

FROM

     `tec_sale_items` tec_sale_items INNER JOIN `tec_sales` tec_sales ON tec_sale_items.`sale_id` = tec_sales.`id`
     INNER JOIN `tec_products` tec_products ON tec_sale_items.`product_code` = tec_products.`code`,
     `tec_customers` tec_customers

WHERE

     tec_sale_items.`sale_id` = $P{parameter1}
```

Me trae los valores pero me los duplica, quien me puede colaborar.

---

[image: este es el resultado que obtengo se me estan repitiendo los valores esta venta 33 solo tiene 3 items]

este es el resultado que obtengo se me estan repitiendo los valores esta venta 33 solo tiene 3 items]

Comment: Puedes agregar el resultado que obtienes y el que deseas obtener?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si te duplica valores es porque tenes relaciones 1 a muchos o muchos a muchos que no estas tomando en cuenta, o fallan las condiciones de join... solo vos lo podras saber...

Comment: ¿Los JOIN expresan **correctamente** la relación que hay entre tus tablas? ¿Los **datos** están bien? Cuando este tipo de consultas no funcionan es por uno de esos dos motivos. Revisa ambos y nos dices. Si no encuentras el problema entonces debes agregar un ejemplo mínimo y verificable con los datos que te están apareciendo duplicados. Para ver lo que está mal puedes quitar uno de los JOIN, si dejan de salir duplicados sabrás que hay un problema en la tabla de ese JOIN que quitaste. Si quitando todos los JOIN siguen saliendo duplicados el problema es la tabla del  `FROM`

Comment: Haces full join con `tec_customers`, debería ser `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Diría que en `tec_customers` existen 2 registros, dado que el _join_ (implícito) no tienen condición, se va a incluir en el resultado todo tantas veces como registros tenga esa tabla.